# How to search a range for multiple pieces of text

Tags: excel, search

I need to search `F$3` through `F$96` for any cell that contain ALL FOUR of `w3`, `x3`, `y3`, and `z3`. 
Return `TRUE` if ANY CELLS in `f$3` to `F$96` contain all four. how do?

Currently I use

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(W3,F$3:F$96)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(X3,F$3:F$96)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Y3,F$3:F$96)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Z3,F$3:F$96)))
```

But if i place this formula in `AA3`, it only checks `f3`, not `f$3` through `f$96`

I need it to check ALL the cells in that range and return true if ONE contains all 4 criteria.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT` and `--` (double negative) are useful to do what you want. As `SUMPRODUCT` expects an array of values, all cells are checked.

This is what I produced as an example (split into multiple lines for readability):

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(--(F$3:F$96=W3))>0)+
 (SUMPRODUCT(--(F$3:F$96=X3))>0)+
 (SUMPRODUCT(--(F$3:F$96=Y3))>0)+
 (SUMPRODUCT(--(F$3:F$96=Z3))>0)
```

The `--` converts all the TRUE/FALSE into 1's and 0's, and then adds them up (as we are only giving 1 list to each `SUMPRODUCT`, it doesn't do any multiplication, it just adds). The value returned will be the number of cells that matched the value you are looking for.

As we don't care how many matched, just that at least one matched, we complare result of the `SUMPRODUCT` to see if we got at least one match (`>0`), and all the test results are added together.

The result of this calculation would be **4** if all the numbers are found, **3** if only three are found, and so on.

You can either test for the **4** result, or give people an idea of how many they had match by just giving them the result.

Comment: Sean, this doesn't work by my reading of the question. I think, for example, if `W3:Y3` contain a, b, c and d, then the formula should be true if a cell in `F3:F96` contains "abcd" or "bcda", etc.